# Javascript runs when placed directly, not when called upon by file

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am probably doing something (dumb) wrong,  but i cant seem to figure out what.
Not sure if it matters, but this is on a wordpress site.

The following code is basicly a popup, a click on a url and it opens the current window in a new tab, and opens a popup in the old tab (i was given this code by a sponsor)

If i place the code on my site, simply as shown below, it works perfectly.

But i want to call it from a file. But when it is saved in a file it does not seem to work (in the file i removed the script tags)

and i call it by

```html
<script src="myurl/filename.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Other javascript files that called like that do work on my site

```html
    <script>
   (function() {
    // do stuff
}());
    </script>
```

edit: thnx to floodlitworld's answer it now works,  i still dont understand why though
the end of the wrapper was:

```html
}());
```

and it worked when it was changed to this:

```html
})();
```

What changed when this part was moved: ?

()

Comment: Is the `script` tag loading the file at the same place where the `script` tag containing the code was before? Do you see any error message in the console of your browser?

Comment: yeh, the file is called in the same location/order the script tags containing the code were. i also dont see any issues in my console (apart from some unrelated css issues there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used the Network tab on the browser's dev panel to check that the external JS file is actually loading correctly?

Also, does your external script have the same

```
(function() {
    // do stuff
})()
```

wrapper around it?

Comment: in the network tab it shows status 200, there does not seem to be an issue with that (also when i change the file name to another javascript file, that file works fine)

as for the wrapper, what i have seems to be different from what you posted there
i have: (but what confuses me is that this javascript does work fine when placed in the html directly), it just doesnt work when i call it from a file
(function () {
   // do stuff
}());

Comment: so my originally wrapper ended with:
}()); 
when i changed it to what you said (with a semi colon next to it)
})();

it worked,  why did this change it?

Comment: The format I gave you was for an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

The parentheses at the end tell the function between the previous brackets to execute.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, might delete answer:

maybe

```
(function() {}) ();
```

is simply the correct punctuation. (?)

not:

```
(function() {} ());
```

Comment: yeh that was correct (i did already get it working) but i dont understand why moving the () makes it work (i dont normally use javascript)
what did the ()  part do, that moving it made it work?

Comment: That's the punctuation... I don't know what else to say. When you don't use the proper punctuation, it doesn't work, when you do, it does.